# flag increment error inside def() statement in python

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, opencv

I write a sample code which print mouse click and if click on particular point then a flag incremented by one . when click on some other position then the same flag decremented by one.Also print the flag .but there have some error occurs.How to avoid it ?

```
import cv2
import glob
image_count=0
global file_number
global total_files
file_number=30
def click_event(event, x, y, flags, param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:       
    print x, y
    if 28<x<287 and 29<y<65:                          #open     
        file_number=100
        print(file_number)      
    if 33<x<144 and 89<y<120:                         #prev
        file_number=file_number-1       
        print(file_number)
    if 163<x<283 and 91<y<122:                         #next
        file_number=file_number+1
        print(file_number)

imdir = '/media/aju/21D83BA336AE27A9/idcard/'
ext = ['png', 'jpg', 'gif']    # Add image formats here

files = []
[files.extend(glob.glob(imdir + '*.' + e)) for e in ext]

images = [cv2.imread(file) for file in files]
print(files)
total_files=len(files)
print(total_files)
img = cv2.imread('menu.png')
cv2.imshow('Main Menu', img)
cv2.setMouseCallback("Main Menu", click_event)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

---

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "final07_11_2018.py", line 14, in click_event
    file_number=file_number-1       
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'file_number' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: What value should `filenumber` have if `x == 40` and `y == 100`?

Comment: actually x and y are positions of mouse click on the image .On the first click of the corresponding positions gives these errors.  ** Answer for you :- **       ` it depends on number of clicks `

Comment: I intended to hint you to the cause of the error. If `x`/`y` have these values, only the `#prev` case is entered, in which `filenumber = filenumber - 1` is executed. But if this happens on the first click, `filenumber` was never defined before, which results in the error you see. You need to decide what should be the initial value of `filenumber` so that the `#prev` block can be executed in all cases (or make sure that it cannot be entered unless the `#open` case has been entered before).

Comment: but x==40 and y==100 is only a single position.If my first click on the position satisfies #open works and after this if i press a position satisfies #prev will causes the same error .(according to concept first file_number set to 100on first click in #open and on the next click in #prev it would be 99,is it correct?,but why the error occured ? )

Answer (score 0):

I solved it declare the variable `file_number` as `global` inside `def()`.